# Default Upload Location for asset fields on a User...?

Tags: assets

when setting a Default Upload Location for a field that’s attached to a User, what’s the variable to use that would ensure the file is uploaded to the User I’m editing’s account in the back end, and not *my admin* user account - which is what {{currentUser.username}} does?

I haven't been able to find out and everything I've tried hasn't worked. e.g., Could not resolve the subpath “{user.username}”. And {{ user.username }} uploads to a folder for my admin account.

Comment: Have you tried just `{user}` or if you're in a Matrix block, `{owner.user}`?

Comment: Yep; "Could not resolve the subpath “{user}”." is what I get :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the folders to be named after the users' IDs (since they won't change), the subpath should be `{id}`.

Comment: Bizarrely, {id} allowed me to save the User with the uploaded Asset, but browsing the Asset section the file I uploaded does not show up in the folder created for the User ID. It's a blank folder. In fact the image doesn't show up anywhere in the Assets section.

[edit] My bad, I hadn't created the folder for the asset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this looking for similar reason for error. Went with this in the end, as it adds some folder readability should I need to access uploads by user outside of the CP.

```
{% if fullName|length %}{fullName|lower}-{% endif %}{id}
```